# why i cant hear my voice when i connect to two Baofeng uv82 to the same repeater frequencies

Tags: uhf, baofeng, repeater, tone-squelch, squelch

I have two baofeng uv-82 and I connected both to the same repeater frequency, and once I press the ptt button I can hear the squelch sound on both radios. However, once I talk to one radio, I don't hear my voice!!. i used the repeaterbook website and i want to connect to the following frequency below:
Downlink:   439.250000 ( is my receiving frequency once saved)
Uplink: 431.650000     ( is my transmitting frequency once ptt pushed)
Offset: -7.6 MHz       (  once i add the offset, the radio doesn't connect to the repeater.
as i save the the frequencies manually)
Uplink Tone:    94.8   ( here i go to T-CTCS and R-CTCS and put this number on both radios)
so once i save, i find the frequency on 439250, and i push to talk it goes to 431.650, as they requested. However, once i push to talk i cant hear my voice but i only hear the squelch on both radios that is coming from the repeater.!!!
i am sure i am doing something wrong, so i would highly appreciate if someone can help, as i am not an expert on hamradios so please use answers that i can understand :)
below is the link i am programming my radios to it:
https://www.repeaterbook.com/row_repeaters/details.php?state_id=TR&ID=8084

Thank you for your support

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/10211/2988

Comment: I assume you're doing this for testing. The description in the link provided in the previous comment is almost certainly what you are experiencing.  For actual (not testing) communication, you should use simplex communication without a repeater. In Canada, you are required by the radio regulations to do that, and that is likely true in other countries.

Comment: @Deepstop Why do you say *For actual (not testing) communication, you should use simplex communication without a repeater...*?

Comment: Agree w @tomnexus this is probably due question: [Why can't I hear myself from a second radio when bouncing off a repeater?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/why-cant-i-hear-myself-from-a-second-radio-when-bouncing-off-a-repeater)

Comment: Hi everyone, and thank you for your comments. the first link from tomnexus i have read it before asking my question. As for Mike Waters, i have no problem when i put them in simplex mode, i just want to know what i am doing wrong when i connect both to repeater . and i checked webmarc link but still it didnt solve my issue. i think if one of you guys can have video call with me, you will find out what is the mistake i am doing. i will keep trying till i fix it.

Comment: The radios are too close together to talk on a repeater.  The receiver can't filter out the transmitter's frequency.  It's like trying to listen to someone on the other side of the room when someone is screaming at you next to you.  The linked answer is correct.

Comment: To put it another way, the best way to solve your issue is to put more distance between the two radios. It might also help to turn the power down. To your other question, it is always preferable to use simplex if you can, so that others who can't are able to use the repeater.

Comment: Deepstop and user10489: thank you for the answers and u will try it today by keeping one at home while I go for a drive and test them. As for the simplex, I always use it but as mentioned above, I wanted to test the repeaters around istanbul. Thank you again and Once I try them, will let you know 

Comment: You might not even need to go that far.  100ft might be far enough.